# Search where HABTM is in another model's HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have two models, Subcontractor:

```
class Subcontractor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trades
end
```

And Bid:

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trades
end
```

I'm trying to find all subcontractors who have trades that match the trades of a particular bid. I've tried something along the lines of `Subcontractor.where(trade_ids: bid.trade_ids)` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you say why exactly that query didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I finally did the query:

```
Subcontractor.joins(:trades).where('trades.id' => bid.trade_ids).uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an array to an `ActiveRecord` query, ActiveRecord is smart enough to know that you mean all items `IN` the array.

Have you tried

```
Subcontractor.where(trade_ids: bid.trades.pluck(:id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way also

```
Subcontractor.where("trade_id in (?)", bid.trades.pluck(:id))
```